# VSCode changes ' to " on save (autoSave)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, prettier

-Edited- 
First of all - thanks for the answers. 
settings->quote indeed looks like
the right direction. 
That being said..
 I understand that there is no reality in which I get to keep *BOTH* my single, *AND* double quotes,
and just turn off ONLY the quote thing checker/fixer style.


-Original-

My VSCode changes the [`'`] char to [`"`] automatically every time it saves.

I have the autosave feature (out of focus, etc.) turned on.

So.. at this point, writing NodeJS is becoming insufferable.

Tried looking through my extensions, settings, and even deleted all the unused and old ones.

Nothing.

I'm down to these 5, and can't seem to find the answer (Of course, "Prettier" was the first thing I checked. so if it's there, I either didn't get it, or missed it.)

[image]

Comment: In the VS Code settings, try searching for `quote`

Answer (score 0):

In the settings of VS Code, just search for `javascript.preferences.quoteStyle` to get the exact result. But this is the setting you need to change in order to tell Prettier that you want single quotes instead of double quotes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can tell prettier that you prefer single quotes by having a [config file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) (for example, a `.prettierrc` at the root of your project that has `singleQuote` set to `true`. The default is `false`.

```json
{
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a vue3/ASP.Net app I recently imported. I disabled the Prettier extension, which I see you have installed. After reloading VSCode, the problem went away. Not sure why, I have it set the single quotes, as the comments above suggest. Perhaps a bug in the extension...